# select a date that is lesser than today

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like below.

```
id  date            value
12  2017-12-11      250
13  2017-12-11      256
14  2017-11-10      300
15  2017-11-09      400
```

I need to write a query where I can get the prior date of today.
Like if today is 2017-12-11, the query should only return

```
id  date        value
14  2017-11-10  300
```

Please help me how can I get this.

Comment: what database system are you using ?

Comment: @Squirrel from the user profile, it looks like all his questions are about postgresql

Comment: @Kushal LNU you have to choose one technology (sql-server or mysql or postgresql) just remove unwanted tags. Also it is good to visit the [Tour Page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) to get your "informed" badge and to learn more about this site

Comment: @Squirrel I am using PostgreSQL. I need to return the second max date. Not all the prior date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*because the initial question was tagged with [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server)[mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql)[postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) i provided 3 versions of solution*

**SQL Server version**

You can use `Convert(date, getdate())`  to get today date *(without time)*, and with a simple query you can get what you are looking for

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
From MyTable 
Where [date] < Convert(date, getdate()) 
ORDER BY [date] desc
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f6f7c/1/0)

**PostgreSQL version**

```
SELECT  *
From MyTable 
Where date < current_date
ORDER BY date desc
limit 1
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d7c37/6/0)

**MySQL version**

```
SELECT  *
From MyTable 
Where date < current_date
ORDER BY date desc
limit 1
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7c37e/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from yourtable t where t.date_value < getdate()
```